# DBUtils QueryRunner instantiation

Tags: java, object, servlets, instantiation, apache-commons-dbutils

I have a webservice that instantiates a single [QueryRunner](http://commons.apache.org/dbutils/apidocs/org/apache/commons/dbutils/QueryRunner.html) with a data source on initialization. It uses this one `QueryRunner` object for all servlet requests from multiple different servlets used by the webapp by passing it around as a servlet context attribute. I.e.:

```
// in servlet context listener (on app initialization)
QueryRunner myQueryRunner = new QueryRunner(myDataSource);
myServletContext.setAttribute("queryRunner", myQueryRunner);

// in the servlets
QueryRunner myQueryRunner = (QueryRunner) myServletContext.getAttribute("queryRunner");
myQueryRunner.query(myStoredProcedure, handler, params)
```

I am trying to figure out if that is a bottleneck. Should the servlets be instantiating a new `QueryRunner` with every request instead?

When looking around for an answer I also found this [AsyncQueryRunner](http://commons.apache.org/dbutils/apidocs/org/apache/commons/dbutils/AsyncQueryRunner.html). But I just got more confused because the explanations in the API docs for [QueryRunner](http://commons.apache.org/dbutils/apidocs/org/apache/commons/dbutils/QueryRunner.html) and [AsyncQueryRunner](http://commons.apache.org/dbutils/apidocs/org/apache/commons/dbutils/AsyncQueryRunner.html) say the exact same thing.

I looked through the examples [here](http://commons.apache.org/dbutils/examples.html) and it seems that it should be instantiated with every request but I am not sure if that is just because it is example code.

In other words, when using DBUtils `QueryRunner` should I:

1. Use a single `QueryRunner` instance for every request? (what I am
   doing now)
2. Instantiate a new `QueryRunner` with every servlet request?
3. Use a single `AsyncQueryRunner` instance for every request?

Comment: I am trying to figure out if that is a bottleneck. it is no possible. QueryRunner is a thread-safe class, you can use a single QueryRunner for all requests.  AsyncQueryRunner use ThreadPool to process every query, but it is not as normal situation, it is only used in long query spend.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

QueryRunner is a thread safe class because it is stateless so you can use a single instance in a multithread environment without any problem.

All methods are self contained and so there's no need to sinchronize method access so you can also exclude bottlenecks.

I use it in production environment without problem but my implementation follow the pattern "instantiate a new QueryRunner with every statement" because it's a delegating class with no state so no heavy initialization and no heap consuming and I avoid to use singleton or other shared instance to store such type of class.

AsyncQueryRunner is also thread safe but its purpose and usage is completely different (see http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-dbutils/examples.html). It is used to create a non-blocking call for long running statement. It could be useful if your business layer needs to be asynchronous.

In conclusion:

- use single QueryRunner instance from multiple threads (each request one thread?) has no counterindication but also no adavantages, but a little bit of code is needed somewhere to manage this instance
- use new QueryRunner instance for each thread or even for each statement you want to delegate through it has two main adavantages: simple and localized use and no instances are in memory if there's no need for them.
- AsyncQueryRunner requires a cumbersome management of the query response so use it only if you need an asynchronous behaviour in your business code.